# Self-sizingなUICollectionViewCellを実装したときに出るAutoLayoutのエラーを解決したい

Tags: swift, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`UICollectionView` を使って2カラムのリストを表示しようとしています。
そのとき `UICollectionViewCell` 上のviewにAspectRatio制約とWidth制約を付け、Width制約の定数を操作することで高さが自動で決まるようしています。
実行すると期待している見た目になってはいるのですがAutoLayoutのエラーが出てしまいそれを解決できないでいます。

再現コードを示します：

```swift
import UIKit

class MyColletionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "TEST"
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            // AspectRatio制約を付ける
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        ])

        // 幅を操作するためにWidth制約を付ける
        widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                                             attribute: .width,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: nil,
                                             attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 100)
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(MyColletionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyColletionViewCell")
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyColletionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyColletionViewCell
        // UICollectionViewの半分の幅を設定する
        cell.widthConstraint.constant = collectionView.frame.width / 2
        return cell
    }
}
```

エラーは次の通りです：

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4320 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.height == 2*UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e41e0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fac7a025a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4230 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fac7a025a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4280 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.trailing == UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e42d0 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.bottom == UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4050 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.width == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4320 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.height == 2*UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-07-10 23:54:54.920262+0900 SelfSizing[46764:1726414] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4190 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.width == 187.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4230 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fac7a025a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4280 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.trailing == UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fac7a025a90.width == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000001e4190 UILabel:0x7fac7a025dc0'TEST'.width == 187.5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージに含まれる`UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width`がよくわからないので、検索してみたところ、こんな記事が見つかりました。

[Auto-layout: What creates constraints named UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width & Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23910943/6541007)

どうも、`UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width`と言うのは制約を付けた要素を取り囲んでいる要素のことで、今の場合`MyColletionViewCell`(の`contentView`)のことのようです。

で、`UICollectionViewCell`の場合は、幅:50, 高さ:50という暗黙の制約がついており、それが他の制約と矛盾してしまうみたいです。

承認された回答での回避策は`priority`を調整するということだったので、やってみました。

暗黙の制約がどこにどうかかっているかわからなかったので、自分で付ける制約の方を調整します。

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "TEST"
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            // AspectRatio制約を付ける
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        ].map {$0.priority = .defaultHigh;return $0}) //<-

        // 幅を操作するためにWidth制約を付ける
        widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                                             attribute: .width,
                                             relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: nil,
                                             attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                             multiplier: 1,
                                             constant: 100)
        widthConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh //<-
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }
```

他に何かうまいやり方があるかもしれませんが、とりあえずこれでエラーメッセージは表示されなくなり、所望の制約が正しく機能しているようです。